# Python random number puzzle not working

Tags: python

Whenever I say "no" to the `"would you like to attempt the puzzle?"` thing, nothing comes up. I even just put a `print ("test")` after all of that code once and it didn't execute the test.

```
puzzle1 = raw_input ("The cave has a small golden inscription on the door with a dial for imputting numbers. A puzzle! Would you like to attempt the puzzle?")
    #Puzzle 1
if path1 == "2":
    while breakhold2 == 0:
        if path1 == "2":
            if puzzle1.lower in ["Yes", "Ye", "Y", "y", "ye", "yes"]:
                print ("You press the button on the door. A small dial turns quickly and picks a random number between 1 and 50. Now you must guess the number being told to go 'higher' or 'lower'. You have only 5 tries to guess the random number.")

if path1 == "2":
    while breakhold2 == 0:
        if path1 == "2":
            if puzzle1.lower in ["Yes", "Ye", "Y", "y", "ye", "yes"]:
                from random import randrange
                puzzle1number = randrange(1,51)
                puzzle1number2 = raw_input ("What is the first guess? You have 5 tries left.")
                if int(puzzle1number2) == puzzle1number:
                    print ("You did it first try! Lucky you!")
                if int(puzzle1number2) > puzzle1number:
                    print ("Lower!")
                if int(puzzle1number2) < puzzle1number:
                    print ("Higher!")
                if int(puzzle1number2) == puzzle1number:
                    breakhold2 += 1
                    break
                else:
                    puzzle1number3 = raw_input ("What is the second guess? You have 4 tries left.")
                if int(puzzle1number3) == puzzle1number:
                    print ("You did it second try! Great guessing!")
                if int(puzzle1number3) < puzzle1number:
                    print ("Higher!")
                if int(puzzle1number3) > puzzle1number:
                    print ("Lower!")
                if int(puzzle1number2) == puzzle1number or int(puzzle1number3) == puzzle1number:
                    breakhold2 += 1
                    break
                else:
                    puzzle1number4 = raw_input ("What is the third guess? You have 3 tries left.")
                if int(puzzle1number4) == puzzle1number:
                    print ("You did it third try! Great guessing!")
                if int(puzzle1number4) < puzzle1number:
                    print ("Higher!")
                if int(puzzle1number4) > puzzle1number:
                    print ("Lower!")
                if int(puzzle1number4) == puzzle1number or int(puzzle1number4) == puzzle1number:
                    breakhold2 += 1
                    break
                else:
                    puzzle1number5 = raw_input ("What is the fourth guess? You have 2 tries left.")
                if int(puzzle1number5) == puzzle1number:
                    print ("You did it fourth try! That came kind of close.")
                if int(puzzle1number5) < puzzle1number:
                    print ("Higher!")
                if int(puzzle1number5) > puzzle1number:
                    print ("Lower!")
                if int(puzzle1number5) == puzzle1number or int(puzzle1number5) == puzzle1number:
                    breakhold2 += 1
                    break
                else:
                    puzzle1number6 = raw_input ("What is the fifth and final guess? This is your last try!")
                    if int(puzzle1number6) == puzzle1number:
                        print ("Finally! Got it on the last go!")
                    else:
                        print ("Blast! The small dial clicks and becomes unmovable. Whatever treasure was in there is now locked inside. I wonder why that was a lock?")
                        breakhold2 += 1
                        break

if path1 == "2":
    while breakhold2 == "0":
        if puzzle1.lower in ["No", "no", "n", "N"]:
            print ("You decide not to attempt the puzzle.")          
            breakhold2 += 1
            break
```

Comment: `while breakhold2 == "0":`  should probably be `while breakhold2 == 0:` like the rest.

Comment: Shouldn't `.lower` be `.lower()`?

Comment: `puzzle1number2` can only ever be one thing at a time, `elif` would be useful

Comment: You're setting `puzzle1 = ...` and then testing `if path1 == ...` -- and you never show what you set that `path1` name to, and are completely ignoring `puzzle1`.  Maybe you're not showing us your actual code?  That makes it hard to offer any help, you know...:-)

Comment: Sorry about not saying about path1. There is a simple piece of code earlier on that says - "path1 = raw_input ("Go left or go right?")". Including all of the code from this would have been massive, this is a large project, and I only felt the need to put in the part I need fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`puzzle1.lower in ['yes', 'no', 'whatever', ...]` will always be False.

Use instead `puzzle1.lower() in [....]`.

Check:

```
answer = 'Yes'

print(answer.lower)    
print(answer.lower in ['yes', 'y'])
```

versus:

```
answer = 'Yes'

print(answer.lower())    
print(answer.lower() in ['yes', 'y'])
```

Comment: @Lixerman99 `puzzle1.lower` is just a reference to a function; whereas `puzzle1.lower()` is actually the string result of that function.